# Wildcards to accept any type with interface

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use generics to accept any object that implements the `Client` interface, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
public interface Client {
  public void makeMove();
}

public MyClient implements Client {
  public MyClient(Server server) {
    server.connectClient(this);
  }
}
```

The error I get above is: `The method connectClient(Class<? extends FanoronaClient>) in the type Server is not applicable for the arguments (GUIClient)`

The server with generics:

```
public class Server {
  private Class<? extends Client> client_;

  public void connectClient(Class<? extends Client> client) {
    client_ = client;
    client_.makeMove(); // type error here
  }
}
```

And the error here is `The method makeMove() is undefined for the type Class<capture#7-of ? extends Client>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How come your MyClient class does not implement the makeMove method from implementing interface ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on the class [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), which doesn't exist.  What you actually want is an *implementation* of your class/interface to be passed to your method.

Your `connetClient` method should look something like this instead:

```
public void connectClient(Client client) {
    client.makeMove(); // no more type error
}
```

Of course if you want to keep a reference to this in your class, you will have to change the `_client` member of your `Server` class to also be of type `Client`.

I don't think you want to be using generics at all in this example...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out :

```
public class Server {
      private Class<? extends Client> client_;

      public void connectClient(Class<? extends Client> client) {
        client_ = client;
        client.newInstance().makeMove(); // no error here 
      }
    }
```